# How do you return a query from knex typescript operations instead of results?

Tags: mysql, database, typescript, knex.js

I am using knex to perform operations on my sql db. Is there a way I can sort-of lazy execute the query?
My code looks like this

```
const results = await knex({dbconfig})('table1')
                           .select('col1').where('...')
```

I want to make some typescript operations and check some conditions to perform further operations.
If I try to perform them by simply writing `results.where('...')` it fails saying `TypeError: results.where is not a function`.

What I am doing right now is:

```
if (condition1){
const results = await knex(..).(some operations)
    }
else{
const results = await knex(..).(some operations + some other operarations)
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here, as I think you've discovered, is to use the object that Knex returns. However, you don't have to reassign it each time, just call the method on it. So:

```js
async function getCustomers(options) {
  const customers = knex('customers').where({ someCondition });

  if (options.region) {
    customers.where({ region: options.region });
  }

  return customers;
}
```

Note that `return await` is redundant in an `async` function: you'll have to `await` in the calling code anyway, so you're really just returning a promise.

Comment: I get it, I wasn't aware if reassignment is necessary. And you are right about the await being redundant here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.
I ended up removing await and using var nd putting it while returning so now

```
var results = knex(...).someOperations(..)
if(condition1)
    results=results.someOtherOperations(..)
else if(condition2)
     results = results.someOtherOps2(..)
return await results
```